# Why assigning list to another list produce 'None'?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why printing a list that was assigned  using another list will give `None`. The code is as follows.

```
A=[]
for i in range(12,4,-2):
    A.append(i)
A_A=A.append(4)
print(A)
print(A_A)
```

In above code, why `print(A_A)` gives  `None`?.

Thank you.

Comment: It's specifically with the `list.append` method. It returns None instead of another list.

Comment: because `A.append(4)` returns None. You want to do `A_A = A + [4]` perhaps

Comment: It is a function that only has a `side-effect` (appending), nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
list.append()
```

modifies the `list` that it's called on. It doesn't return anything - thus, when you try to assign its return value to `A_A`, you get `None`.

You'll notice that, in your code, `4` *was* successfully appended to `A`, as you'd expect. The rationale here is, if you already know what you're trying to add, why bother returning it? Or, put another way - what could `list.append()` possibly return that would be useful? The conclusion was that it couldn't; thus, `list.append()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Although I marked the answer correct, the question is why it printed `A' then?

Comment: Well, `print(None)` prints `None`, it's as simple as that. Since `A_A` is `None`, then `print(None)` prints `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Append does not return anything, it just modifies the original list.